# hybrid remote app header is not getting hide

Tags: mobile, mobilesdk, sfdcmobilesdk-android, hybrid-remote

i am using hybrid remote app, and running it on android emulator.
The app which is connected to sandbox does not have app header after login.

same when used for production, it shows app header after login.

I don't want app header to show after login.
What should i do?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

It was happening because of url
https://xyz.com/asd/ will not hide the header
https://xyz.com will hide the header